# "Will Have Done" tense- meaning and examples

Tags: future-tense

Looking for sufficient definitions and explanations of this tense, I noticed that one meaning will usually refer to something someone "will have done" as something that "will have been done\completed". While I do realize this is one independent reason to use this tense, I don't quite get a lot by a definition of a tense which uses the tense it attempts to define. It would really help me if someone could clarify the subject, including regarding similar forms, such as: Will Have: gone, finished, completed, ended...All(Or most V3 verbs).

Comment: https://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/future-2-simple - google is your friend.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I did visit that link previously, but I still wasn't fully convinced. Is it to formally ensure something will occur?

Comment: You should take care with the phrase "will have done."  The British use it in a way that Americans don't.  For example: Q: Have you gone to buy nappies yet?  A: No, but I will have done by the time Mary gets here with the baby.  In American English, one would only say, "No, but I will have by the time Mary gets here with the baby."  The British tend to say "will have done," where others would simply say "will have" or where "done" stands for some other verb, like in the example "done" stands in for "gone."

Comment: Do you mean that it is similar to saying "I do\did" referring to a certain verb already mention? I don't really understand why it shouldn't be used by American English speaker, but I did observe nuances and actual differences between the tongues, that included. Thank you for exposing me to that fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tense is called *Future II simple*

> **Usage**
>
> - action that will have been finished by a future time
>
> Example: Don’t worry, he will have repaired the bike by then.
>
> - supposition about what happened
>
> Example: He will probably have noticed that his bike is broken.

[Source1](https://english.lingolia.com/en/grammar/tenses/future-ii-simple)

[Source2](http://ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/future-2-simple)

Comment: The first source was really helpful, as well as the above categories.

Answer (score 0):

Will have done has two meanings:

1. used for saying that you expect an action to be completed before a time in the future.
   We will have gone
   to bed by the time you
    arrive.
2. supposition about what happened
   Example: He will probably have noticed that his bike is broken.
   It is called wine,' said O'Brien with a faint smile. 'You will have read about it in books, no doubt.(1984).